# webpack: How to keep directory structure the same as before compiling the project?

Tags: javascript, webpack

So here is my directory structure：

[image]

and this is my webpack configuration:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: 'src/index/main.js',
        video: 'src/video/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/'),
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: ....
    },
   resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.less'],
        alias: {
            'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
        }
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    },
    plugins: [
        ....some other plugins....
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            mangle: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            chunks: ['index', 'video'],
            minChunks: 2
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            chunks: ['common', 'index'],
            template: 'src/index/index.html',
            inject: false,
            minify: false
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'video.html',
            chunks: ['common', 'video'],
            template: 'src/video/index.html',
            inject: false,
            minify: false
       })
    ]

};
```

after I webpacked my project, I got result as follows:
[image]

And my question is that is it possible to keep my directory structure the same as before webpacking the project? Where did I miss?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've made a few edits to your post: Mainly trying to tone down noise (Thanks/Appreciate any help). They usually clutter posts, so try not to include them in the future. Also: Put errors in block quotes (`>`) for maximum visibility. They're usually the focal point of the post.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, and  I just found that I made a mistake about my problem, so I have to edit it...